# VB6 How to catch an ADO Command Timeout error and display custom MsgBox

Tags: sql-server-2005, vb6

I have looked through all of the VB6 Error Numbers to no avail, and it seems the command object itself takes care of the error messagebox in the background. What I need to know is if their is someway to change the MsgBox for the ADODB.CommandTimeout error itself. My first thoughts were to just catch the error (using error numbers) and then set a MsgBox that way. However, I can't find any documentation on any error numbers handling ADO Events. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I got smart and used this:

```
On Error GoTo ERRS
....
ERRS:
    MsgBox Err.Number
```

This gave me the specific error number to catch (in this case: "-2147217871") and from there use a simple If statement to test if the error number = -2147217871 and if it does, display my MsgBox. Works like a charm (well, as much "charm" as VB6 and ADO has, I guess). I am still getting used to the legacy error handling of VB6. Thanks paulsm4 or your assistance!

Answer (score 1):

For whatever it's worth, the error code is 0x80040e31.  You can Google for "error 80040e31 timeout expired".  And, of course, you can check for that error status in your code.

Here is a list of ADO error codes:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677004%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Alright, so I have a list of generic error codes for the ADO object itself and we know the Run-Time Error. Now, my issue is catching the error myself in VB6 and displaying a custom MsgBox to the user.

Comment: I do have a very compelling reason. I can't post details, but yes, it is compelling enough... i guess *sigh* Anyways, I finally figured it out, posting the answer in a moment.